# react-native-modal-dropdown cannot change selected programmatically

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to change the `_dropdown_select()` method on another event in my code occurs. I'm using [sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown](https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/) in my react native app.
I tried with this as attributes on my `<ModalDropdown>` tag:
`select={(idx)=> this._dropdown_select(idx).bind(this)}`

And my method:

```
_dropdown_select(idx){
    return idx;
}
```

I'm calling it like this:
`this._dropdown_select(0);` inside another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to call the select(idx) of the reference of the Dropdown on your method, from the plugins maker. Can be found [here](https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/issues/89#issuecomment-325920379).
Example:
`this.refs.dropDown.select(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

In the property:

```
<ModalDropdown options={['option 1', 'option 2']}
  onSelect={this._dropdown_select}
  defaultIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
>
  ...
</ModalDropdown>
```

Constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {selectedIndex: '', dropDown:{}}
    this._dropdown_select = this._dropdown_select.bind(this)
}
```

Method:

```
_dropdown_select(event){
   this.setState({selectedIndex: event.target.index, dropDown:event})
}
```

Call select method

```
this.state.dropDown.select(2)
```

Comment: How to call make the `drop down` select index programmatically from within another method, how should I call it? How can I make the `dropdown` select an index, of my choice?

Comment: Have a look at select method

Comment: `_dropdown_select(event) {
        this.setState({ selectedIndex: event.target.index, dropDown: event })
   }`

says cannot read property `index` of undefined

Comment: Try to console.log(event) then see objects or try event.index

Comment: console.log(event) returns index of option, not any event

Comment: `https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown#methods` I wanted to use the select method, but that isn't working though :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152953/discussion-between-kalaikumar-thangasamy-and-asif).

Answer (score 0):

Also got this working by using .select(ix)

In component:

```
..
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
  sizeSelect: [1,2,3]
 };

 this.sizeRef = React.createRef();
}

handleChange = (e) => {
 this.setState({sizeSelect: [4,5,6]});
 this.sizeRef.current.select(1);
}
..
```

JSX

```
<ModalDropdown
          ref={this.sizeRef}
          options={this.state.sizeSelect}
          textStyle={styles.text}
          dropdownTextStyle={styles.dropText}
          defaultIndex={0}/>
```